# Javascript perform an action when for loop ends

Tags: javascript, for-loop, action

I want to show a loading gif while loop is being executed. And when the loop finishes hide it. For loop lasts for several seconds.

```
$("#loading").removeClass('hidden');
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            clearInfo(i);
            loadInfo(i, getInfo());
        }
$("#loading").addClass('hidden');
```

This is not working. I suppose the last addClass is executed just after the removeClass and is not waiting for the loop...

One approach should be, insert the loop in a function with callback, but isn't there any easier way?

Regards,

Comment: If you're using JQuery you can use methods like `.hide()` and `.show()`. By this same token `.toggle()` does both of those but flipping back and forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is running in a single thread. Blocking this thread by complex synchronous computation is not a good idea. Checkout [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers).

If `loadInfo` is asynchronous operation you can use promises like this:

```
// show your loading indicator

var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    clearInfo(i);

    // loadInfo returns promise
    promises.push(loadInfo(i, getInfo()));
}
Q.all(promises)
  .then(function () {
    // hide your loading indicator
  });
```

Solution with callbacks will be a messy and dirty (according to my personal opinion).

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something along the lines of this:

```
$("#loading").removeClass('hidden');
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    clearInfo(i);
    loadInfo(i, getInfo());
    if ( i == 9 ) {
        // this is the final pass through the loop
        $("#loading").addClass('hidden');
    }
}
```